# Excell formula - is any other way? seconds to dd:hh:mm

Tags: excel

Hello,

I tried to convert data in cell from seconds to dd:hh:mm format  so
 far I have created formula and it works fine but is any other way?

> =IF(INT(A1/86400)<>"",CONCATENATE(INT(A1/86400),":",IF(INT(MOD(A1,86400)/3600)<10,"0"&INT(MOD(A1,86400)/3600),INT(MOD(A1,86400)/3600)),":",IF(INT(MOD(MOD(A1,86400),3600)/60)<10,"0"&INT(MOD(MOD(A1,86400),3600)/60),INT(MOD(MOD(A1,86400),3600)/60)),""),IF(INT(MOD(A1,86400)/3600)<10,"0"&INT(MOD(A1,86400)/3600),INT(MOD(A1,86400)/3600))&":"&IF(INT(MOD(MOD(A1,86400),3600)/60)<10,"0"&INT(MOD(MOD(A1,86400),3600)/60)&INT(MOD(MOD(A1,86400),3600)/60),""))

by default I used A1 cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=TEXT(A1/86400,"dd:hh:mm")` is one way.

Comment: let see 5603 seconds My formula returns 0:01:33 (dd:hh:mm)

=TEXT(A1/86400,"dd:hh:mm")  retunrs 00:15:33 - which is wrong

Comment: On my machine, my formula returns 00:01:33, as you'd expect. Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: incredible how simple way you have found :)

Comment: Note that "dd" format won't show a number > 31, so if A1 is 8640000 (100 days) you get a result of "09:00:00" instead of "100:00:00". If that's an issue change to this version `=INT(A1/86400)&TEXT(A1/86400,":hh:mm")`

Comment: @barry houdini: Yes that's a better solution at the expense of clarity. Put as an answer and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `"dd"` number format (and used in `TEXT` function) can be problematic in two ways

1) It won't show a number > 31

2) It may give the wrong result if you are using 1904 date system

In both cases this is because "dd" is actually showing the day of the month, (count starts at the first day of relevant date system) rather than actual elapsed days.

... so for large values of A1 (>= 2,764,800) it's best to use `INT` function as per your original formula, so to combine that with `Bathsheba's` suggestion you can use this version

`=INT(A1/86400)&TEXT(A1/86400,":hh:mm")`

Comment: Thanks! It is very important as some value exceeded 7 257 600 sec == 6 months

Answer (score 0):

The `TIME` function should work for you as it accepts `=TIME(Hours,Minutes,Seconds)`

So this works:
`=TIME(0,0,5000)`
1:23 AM

Comment: There's a limitation, though, the seconds value can't exceed 32767

Comment: ah, did not know that! Your answer would work much better as a consequence if they are converting a unix style timestamp